headers and footers defined with fancyhdr are ignored on special page for floats only
I define my headers and footers like this:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\addtolength{\headwidth}{4cm}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\iffloatpage{\textsl{\leftmark}}{\textsl{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{\thepage}{\thepage}}

On "normal" pages, this works perfectly fine. The header looks like this:
"Chapter (Chapter Number). (Chapter Name)" and there is also a horizontal line at the bottom of the head. And the page number is in the footer, in the center.
However, this doesn't work on pages with only figures and/or tables.
I thought that the additions of \iffloatpage would fix this, but it doesn't.
Where is the error?
Edit: Here is a more complete example:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\addtolength{\headwidth}{4cm}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\iffloatpage{\textsl{\leftmark}}{\textsl{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{\thepage}{\thepage}}

\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-2.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1.2}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1.2}

%\cfoot{\thepage}
 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0300}{\`}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\'}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % This defines the font-encoding you prefer to use
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,bindingoffset=1cm,centering,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitV]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % No indentation between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt} % Space between paragraphs

% Tables
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}


% Needed for code listings
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

% Subfigure
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatpag} % to move floatpagenr to topright

% Fußnote
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{-0.8em}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{afterpage} % needed for empty page after front

\usepackage[all]{nowidow} % prevents overhanging paragraphs
\usepackage{acronym} % allow acronyms

% The "num", "si", and "SI" commands for typesetting numbers, units, and numbers-with-units
%\usepackage[range-phrase=--,per-mode=symbol-or-fraction,binary-units=true,range-units=single,list-units=single,detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{silence}\WarningsOff[latexfont]
\AtBeginDocument{
    \DeclareSIUnit\decibel{dB}
}


%%===================================
% Custom definitions
    
% List with less space between items
\newenvironment{cList}{
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{itemize}}

% Enumeration with less space between items
\newenvironment{cEnum}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}

% Space LoL
\let\Chapter\chapter
\def\chapter{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}\Chapter}

% Rename listings and toc
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Listings}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codeword}{v}{%
\texttt{\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\blinddocument
\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

May I also suggest package {mwe} (see more about mwe) that provides also example  images, e.g. \includegraphics [ width =.48\ linewidth ] { example−image−a } if you want to reproduce this kind of behavior.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
Thanks, I edited my question accordingly

@GiuTeX I used mwe to edit my question, thanks!

There is a lot of code in your example, which is not needed for a MWE. And some code even does not make sense, e.g., loading color after xcolor already has been loaded. What usually also does not make sense is your:
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\iffloatpage{\textsl{\leftmark}}{\textsl{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{\thepage}{\thepage}}
\usepackage{floatpag}

because here you have a conditional with the identical then and else part. Replacing the conditional by only one case and removing floatpag already solves your problem (which once again is an example for: keep your preamble clean to avoid problems).
Reduced MWE, with the changes above to solve the problem:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}% Note: twoside is already the default, you can remove it.
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% NOTE: It is better to load this AFTER setting up the
                     % page margins (using package geometry), because
                     % otherwise fancyhdr may use the wrong head width.
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\addtolength{\headwidth}{4cm}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}% CHANGED
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% CHANGED
\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-2.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1.2}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1.2}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,bindingoffset=1cm,centering,includeheadfoot]{geometry}% See note above!

\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % NOTE: Better use package
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}  % parskip!

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}% Note: \begin{figure}[h] makes not sense, use
              % either \begin{figure}[htp] or like here without option
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\blinddocument
\end{document}


On the other hand, if you really need package floatpag and want to use page style fancy also for the float pages, you have to setup the page style of those pages using \floatpagestyle{fancy}. Otherwise the page uses the default headings as documented on the first page of the floatpag user manual:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}% Note: twoside is already the default, you can remove it.
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% NOTE: It is better to load this AFTER setting up the
                     % page margins (using package geometry), because
                     % otherwise fancyhdr may use the wrong head width.
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\addtolength{\headwidth}{4cm}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}% CHANGED
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% CHANGED
\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-2.5mm}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1.2}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1.2}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,bindingoffset=1cm,centering,includeheadfoot]{geometry}% See note above!

\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % NOTE: Better use package
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}  % parskip!

\usepackage{floatpag}% Note: Makes not sense in this example, but added to
\floatpagestyle{fancy}% demonstrate this line

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}% Note: \begin{figure}[h] makes not sense, use
              % either \begin{figure}[htp] or like here without option
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\blinddocument
\end{document}

The result is the same as shown above.
The bottom line would be:

Keep your document preamble clean. Using only those package and preamble definitions, which are really needed, helps to avoid problems and helps to keep track of everything.

Read the documentation of used packages. At least skimming through longer documentation and reading the user section of shorter documentation in full often helps you to understand whether you need the package in question at all and what side effects its use has.

Always minimize your problematic code, not only the body but also the preamble. Minimization helps you to locate the root of a problem and to know, which documentation should be read again.


